# Dynamic values like digit at ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, digit

For example i have smth like this

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <sys:String x:Key="USERNAME_AUTH_CONTENT">User auth success</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and in code behind, sometimes, I use this

```
var text = findRes("USERNAME_AUTH_CONTENT");
```

Is it possible to make smth like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <sys:String x:Key="USERNAME_AUTH_CONTENT">User %username auth success</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and at codebehind

```
var text = findRes("USERNAME_AUTH_CONTENT", "here is i want to paste username");
```

in the end I want see this: 'User AwesomeUserName auth success'

In c++ I can use %d for string. What about c# and resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# uses `{0}`, `{1}`, etc, placeholders for string formatting.

declare xaml resource with a placeholder

```
<system:String x:Key="USERNAME_AUTH_CONTENT">User {0} auth success</system:String>
```

and use `String.Format` to apply formatting:

```
var text = FindResource("USERNAME_AUTH_CONTENT") as string;
if (text != null)
{
    text = String.Format(text, "AwesomeUserName");
}
```

note also that you can use format string directly from xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source='AwesomeUserName', StringFormat={StaticResource USERNAME_AUTH_CONTENT}}"/>
```

(`Source='AwesomeUserName'` is just an example, if you have a view model, then use `Binding Path=SomeProperty`)